# How can I use Gmail to look like a company email address?

Tags: gmail

I can create an email address like `myname@companyname.com` but I am not sure how to send emails from it. So, it is possible to just use Gmail and make it appear as though you are sending email from that company address? And if yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can create an email address like myname@companyname.com ...

You don't necessarily have to use Google Apps (as Prasad states) in order to send email using your Gmail account from a particular email address that you already own and are currently able to *receive* email to (and preferably *send* email from also).

It should be noted that by default, it will use Gmail's SMTP server in order to send email. In this case your Gmail address is still present in the *Sender* header, so depending on the recipients email client, your recipient might see something like:

> From: myname@companyname.com sent via *yourgmailaddress*@gmail.com

Obviously this isn't necessarily appropriate as a business solution. However, you can **use your own SMTP server** that is associated with your domain. This will remove your Gmail address from the sent email and so the email recipient should be none the wiser - it will look as if the email has been sent from your actual email address (no "*via*" notice), because it *has* been sent from your actual email address using your own SMTP server. When setting up the account in Gmail (see below) you must explicitly pick the second option "Send through *yourdomain.com* SMTP servers" and enter your details.

In Gmail Settings > Accounts and Import > "Send mail as:", click "Add another email address you own" and follow the instructions. You will be sent an email to this address with a link that you need to acknowledge to prove that you own this email address. You can choose to send mail via your SMTP server, or use Googles (the default).

In order to receive this email to your Gmail account you can either set up a forward at your current host, or set up Gmail to collect a mailbox using POP3. There is a limit of 5 POP3 accounts you can setup in this way.

This is also a great way to filter out spam if that is a problem - Gmail is a very good spam filter!

However, as mentioned, this isn't necessarily a complete solution - this uses your Gmail account to send/receive email from your server. Your server is still receiving the email. Google Apps allows Google to manage everything.

Comment: should be noted that Google Apps is not free anymore since 6 Dec 2012. So I guess if there are no dollars, there is no email.

Comment: @YannisDran: The method I describe above doesn't use Google Apps (for Business), if that's what you are implying? (Maybe you wanted to comment on the other answer?)

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Starting in 2014 you are required to use your own SMTP when sending from an external email address: support.google.com/mail/answer/22370
A better option would be to: Go to Google Account, Personal Info > Email > Other Emails > "Add a new alternate address"

Comment: @Ross I did add alternate address, but that is not visible as "From address" while composing in gmail !?

Comment: @TechJerk On the last step of adding an alternate address Gmail sends you an email to that new address to confirm that you own it. You need to click on a link in that email to be able to start sending from the new address. Check out my post on how to configure GMail in this case: http://pranas.net/what-is-the-best-email-configuration-of-google-apps-for-a-small-company/

Comment: @Ross it did that but still was not able to figure out the from address :( I was able to log in with alternate address in gmail but I am not sure where to see the from address :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Register your domain on Google Apps (which has now become a premium service).
2. Change your MX entries to point to Google

In case if you haven't already registered with Google Apps, you can always try Outlook.com (not gmail unfortunately :D)